# Issue with Ubuntu 13 Keyboard's Functioning on Spacebar/ Enter/ Backspace

Tags: 13.10, keyboard

Having Ubuntu 13.10 installed on 64 bit machine I am encountering with some issue with Keyboard's Spacebar/ Enter/ Backspace keys. when I click on Spacebar, first for several times, it doesn’t functions at all and sometimes generates these chars '**zcvx**' or '**zcvx,**' the Enter and Backspace either function wrong. can you please let me know why and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked that your keyboard layout is correct? (Look in the settings app for the keyboard section)

Answer (score 0):

You should try another keyboard to see if it's a problem with the keyboard or Ubuntu. It could be a hardware issue. The keys Z, C, V, and X are are all directly above the spacebar and it could be shorting them.

If it is a hardware issue cleaning your keyboard and removing the spacebar and then putting it back in could fix it.

Some links to similar issues are [here](http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/forum/hardware-problems/26440-space-bar-entering-random-letters-performing-random-functions.html) [and here](https://superuser.com/questions/404531/pressing-space-bar-inword-2010-types-character).